# SQL - Totals are all wrong/unexpected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables with part nos and cost of each for diffrent areas.

While run the query for each of them individually, it works fine but when I join tables, I get all the totals wrong.
1st table is part nos list, 2nd is purchase cost and 3rd is selling cost.

I have used left outer join to get all records from table 1 (part list), and proceeded to get sum from table 2 & 3 by joining part no from table1 to table2 & table 1 to table3. It is possible that all parts are not appear in table 2 & 3. 
When I got wrong totals, I tried to move where condition to top along with the join but still getting the same wrong results. Any idea? Any pointer will help.
Additional Data :
I am getting table 2 & 3 from diff systems and need to make a report regularly.

Table 1

```
PART
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Table 2

```
 PART   COST    STREAM  USAGE
A   1   Y   PUF
D   5   Y   PUF
E   4   Y   PUF
G   2   Y   PUF
A   5   Y   PUF
C   1   Y   PUF
S   1       
T   4       
E   2   Y   PUF
```

Table 3

```
PART    SELL    STREAM  USAGE
D   4   Y   PUF
G   2   Y   PUF
A   5   Y   PUF
W   1       
Z   4       
R   2
```

Result expected:

```
PART    SUM OF T2 COST  SUM OF T3 SELL
A   6   5
B   0   
C   1   
D   5   4
E   6   
F   0   
G   2   2
H
```

Here is my code till now.
        ''''

```
SELECT
    dbo.[PART LIST].PART,
    SUM(dbo.[COST ALL].AMT) AS[COST TOTAL],
    SUM(dbo.[SELL ALL].AMT) AS[SELL TOTAL]
FROM
    dbo.[PART LIST]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[SELL ALL]
        ON dbo.[PART LIST].PART = dbo.[SELL ALL].PART
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[COST ALL]
        ON dbo.[PART LIST].PART = dbo.[COST ALL].PART
GROUP BY
    dbo.[PART LIST].PART,
    dbo.[COST ALL].STREAM,
    dbo.[COST ALL].USAGE,
    dbo.[SELL ALL].STREAM,
    dbo.[SELL ALL].USAGE
HAVING
    (dbo.[COST ALL].STREAM = N'Y')
    AND (dbo.[COST ALL].USAGE = N'PUF')
    AND (dbo.[SELL ALL].STREAM = N'Y')
    AND (dbo.[SELL ALL].USAGE = N'PUF')
```

''''

Sorry for initial goofup. Hope above details help to find bug in my code.

Comment: Please show your query.  And sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why do you have _3 different_ tables with part nos and cost of each for diffrent areas?

Comment: Please take [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then have a look at [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Please share your query, sample data and required output.

Comment: Why are you grouping by all of those columns. Just group by `[Part List].[Part]`.

Comment: nm. I see what you were going for here. I think you just painted yourself into a corner with that `HAVING` clause which makes sense because a `WHERE` clause, which feels more appropriate, would have caused your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to act like an `INNER JOIN`. The correct solution here is to filter your right-most tables *BEFORE* joining which can be accomplished with a subquery on each table or additional conditions in your `ON` clauses. I have added an answer with the latter solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you join table 3, you are duplicating table 3 because of the duplicates in table 2.  Then you end up summing the duplicate rows which you do not want.  I believe you should use subqueries for the totals or perhaps windows functions.
Subquery:
**untested**

```
SELECT dbo.[PART LIST].PART, [COST TOTAL], [SELL TOTAL]
FROM dbo.[PART LIST] PL
left outer join (
   select part, sum(amt) as [cost total]
   from dbo.[COST ALL]
   where STREAM = N'Y'
      and USAGE = N'PUF'
   group by part
) C_Total on C_Total.PART = PL.PART
left outer join (
   select part, sum(amt) as [sell total]
   from dbo.[SELL ALL]
   where STREAM = N'Y'
      and USAGE = N'PUF'
   group by part
) S_Total on S_Total.PART = PL.PART
```

You could select `isnull([COST TOTAL],0) [COST TOTAL]` if you want nulls to be 0.

Further explanation:
Consider this query:

```
select part, sum(amt) as [cost total]
from dbo.[COST ALL]
where STREAM = N'Y'
   and USAGE = N'PUF'
group by part
```

It returns 1 row per part and each part's [cost total].  You use these results as if they were a table and join them to the [PART LIST] table.  Because it is grouped by part, there are no duplicates.
You do the same with the [SELL ALL] table.  If you have other tables, you can continue doing the same thing.
I use `left join` because I don't know if the "other" tables ([COST ALL] and [SELL ALL] in this case) have data for EVERY part listed in [PART LIST].  If they do not, then the parts that don't have data will return null because of the `left join`.

Comment: Thanks avery_Iarry. If used directly it gives error. Tried to workout but I am unable to follow your code. Can you pl explain. Thanks again.

Comment: It' useful to tell people the actual error.  Regardless, I realize that there shouldn't be a `GROUP BY` clause in my answer, and so I have removed it.

Comment: Right. error was dbo.[PART LIST] not found. But I was not in office so could not inform you further but I finally made it working. Dont know how. Now I am trying to add another column of totals from one more table. Can you pl explain how your code  works and where I can add sub quary.. Thanks again. Also I want nulls to be zero but your code already provides zero without making any changes as you have suggested.

Comment: @SCM I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: Since I am unable to add my code here due to restrictions, I have posted another question. pl help there. Here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58969208/the-correlation-name-convert-is-specified-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to perform your filter AFTER the `GROUP BY` occurs with a `HAVING` cluase, instead perform the filtering inside your of your `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    dbo.[PART LIST].PART,
    SUM(dbo.[COST ALL].AMT) AS[COST TOTAL],
    SUM(dbo.[SELL ALL].AMT) AS[SELL TOTAL]
FROM
    dbo.[PART LIST]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[SELL ALL]
        ON dbo.[PART LIST].PART = dbo.[SELL ALL].PART
        AND dbo.[SELL ALL].STREAM = N'Y'
        AND dbo.[SELL ALL].USAGE = N'PUF'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[COST ALL]
        ON dbo.[PART LIST].PART = dbo.[COST ALL].PART
        AND dbo.[COST ALL].STREAM = N'Y'
        AND dbo.[COST ALL].USAGE = N'PUF'
GROUP BY
    dbo.[PART LIST].PART
```

Now only relevant records from your Right-most tables are brought through on the `JOIN` and you can properly `GROUP BY` just your `[PART]`.

Comment: Thanks JNevill for your effort but it still gives same old totals which I was getting earlier.