# The correlation name 'CONVERT' is specified multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With the help of @avery_larry, I done  my query but now facing little problem.
I am able to add amount from another 2 tables. Now I have to add amount from same table with two different part no columns.
1st col is part1 and 2nd col is part2. Amount column is same.
When I add sub query, I am getting error that 
"The correlation name `CONVERT` is specified multiple times in a FROM clause." 
`CONVERT`  is table name.
Here is my code.

```
SELECT  dbo.[PART LIST].PART, 
        [COST ALL].[cost total], 
        [SELL ALL].[sell total], 
        [CONVERT].[FROM total], 
        [convert].[TO total]
FROM    
    dbo.[PART LIST] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PART, SUM(AMT) AS [cost total]
     FROM  dbo.[COST ALL] AS [COST ALL_1]
     WHERE (STREAM = N'Y') AND (USAGE = N'MUM')
     GROUP BY PART ) AS [COST ALL] ON [COST ALL].PART = dbo.[PART LIST].PART 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PART, SUM(AMT) AS [sell total]
    FROM dbo.[SELL ALL] AS [SELL ALL_1]
    WHERE (STREAM = N'FSA') AND (USAGE = N'MUM')
    GROUP BY PART ) AS [SELL ALL] ON [SELL ALL].PART = dbo.[PART LIST].PART 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [From PART], SUM(Amt) AS [FROM total]
    FROM dbo.[convert] AS CONVERT_1
    GROUP BY [From PART] ) AS [CONVERT] ON [CONVERT].[From PART] = dbo.[PART LIST].PART 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [TO PART], SUM(Amt) AS [TO total]
    FROM dbo.[convert] AS CONVERT_1
    GROUP BY [TO PART] ) AS [CONVERT] ON [CONVERT].[TO PART] = dbo.[PART LIST].PART
```

Currently, to bypass error, I have made another table with diff name. But having two tables with same data and updating both with new data regularly is a problem. I would rather resolve the error and use only one table.

Pl help.

Comment: Hi @SCM, what database do you use ? Thanks!

Comment: Also, what should this be: [CONVERT].[FROM total]

Comment: Its SQL I am using. I have changed table name convert to kconvert. [KCONVERT].[FROM total] IS TOTAL OF AMOUNT.

Comment: Hi @SCM, SQL is not a database. SQL is a language you use but the databas eis SQLServer, or MySQL or Oracle... It should be nice to know that. For example this question was tag as SQLServer.

Comment: Thanks for Info. I am using SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kryesec is correct.  Each subquery must have a unique alias.

You cannot do this:

```
select *
from (
   select col1
   from table1
) AS [CONVERT]
left outer join (
   select col1
   from table2
) AS [CONVERT] on [CONVERT].col1 = [CONVERT].col1
```

This has `[CONVERT]` defined twice.  Because there is no way to know *which* `[CONVERT].col1` we would actually want, this is invalid and produces the error you see.
You CAN use `[CONVERT]` multiple times as the table your are selecting `FROM`.  To do so, though, each reference must be unique *in scope*.  Meaning you don't have to alias `[CONVERT]` inside each subquery because it is unique inside each subquery (unique in scope).  **BUT** each *subquery* then must have a unique alias, and that is where your error message comes from.

The following is what I think you want your code to be.  Note I removed the aliases from inside the subqueries -- they are unnecessary, though equally they are not causing any problems.  The primary change that should resolve your error is changing the final 2 subqueries from both using alias `[CONVERT]` to using the aliases `[FROM_CONVERT]` and `[TO_CONVERT]` respectively.

```
SELECT  dbo.[PART LIST].PART, 
        [COST ALL].[cost total], 
        [SELL ALL].[sell total], 
        [FROM_CONVERT].[FROM total], 
        [TO_CONVERT].[TO total]
FROM dbo.[PART LIST] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PART, SUM(AMT) AS [cost total]
     FROM  dbo.[COST ALL]
     WHERE (STREAM = N'Y') AND (USAGE = N'MUM')
     GROUP BY PART
) AS [COST ALL] ON [COST ALL].PART = dbo.[PART LIST].PART
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT PART, SUM(AMT) AS [sell total]
    FROM dbo.[SELL ALL]
    WHERE (STREAM = N'FSA') AND (USAGE = N'MUM')
    GROUP BY PART
) AS [SELL ALL] ON [SELL ALL].PART = dbo.[PART LIST].PART
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [From PART], SUM(Amt) AS [FROM total]
    FROM dbo.[convert]
    GROUP BY [From PART]
) AS [FROM_CONVERT] ON [FROM_CONVERT].[From PART] = dbo.[PART LIST].PART 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [TO PART], SUM(Amt) AS [TO total]
    FROM dbo.[convert]
    GROUP BY [TO PART]
) AS [TO_CONVERT] ON [TO_CONVERT].[TO PART] = dbo.[PART LIST].PART
```

As a side note -- you'll probably be happier if you do not use spaces in any of your column names or aliases or tables etc.  This allows you to avoid quotes/square brackets.  In your code, as one example, I would suggest `AS COST_ALL on COST_ALL.PART =` and `select ... sum(amt) as FROM_TOTAL`.
Additionally, it is (very) bad design to use any keywords for names of tables, columns, databases etc.  It looks like you have a table named [CONVERT].  Perhaps you cannot change anything with your design at this point, but you should if you can, and you should remember this for any future projects.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this answer as this is correct.

Comment: @Kryesec answered first -- maybe someone thought I was "stealing" their answer.  The OP seemed maybe confused about the differences between a table, a table alias, and a subquery alias to I expounded.  Also, my original answer maybe deserved a downvote for not pointing out the bad design of using CONVERT as a table name.  I edited my answer to include that information.

Comment: @avery_larry Thanks for detailed explanation and solution. I sure am not able to get multiple field from one table but you have shown a workaround. It works like charm. I have considered your suggetions and will be implementing wherever possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your last 2 sub queries are both alias as [CONVERT]
Change one of them

Comment: Changed [convert] to [kconvert] but still getting same error. [kconvert] is a table name. Cant change table name just in query.

Comment: I told you reserved keywords cant be used as table names or anywhere etc. You got to rename your table as reserved keywords are default sql objects that have a certain meaning and purpose like Convert could be a default database object function to convert some values etc.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be still Convert is reserved keyword. Change it to some other name convert1 etc. The already aliased in your query i guess should have given you some error before aliasing too.

Comment: Changed [convert] to [kconvert] but still getting same error. [kconvert] is a table name. Cant change table name just in query.

Comment: Using a keyword as a table name is bad design.  But it cannot cause the error in the original question.  This answer is only useful as a comment regarding the database's design.

Comment: @avery_larry Try this query `Select * from table as t` where table is a reserved keyword and let me know if you get reserved keyword error or not. Each database sql has its default system keywords that aint be used other than in the context they should

Comment: I'm well aware of things that cannot be done.  Your answer still doesn't answer the actual question asked and your example still cannot cause the error in the original question.  Based on the code presented by the OP, one should presume [CONVERT] was successfully created as a table in their database **OR** one should presume the OP changed the names of the tables to simply be used as examples of their actual database design.

Comment: `select * from [table] as t` works just fine.  It's terribly bad design, but it works without error.

Comment: Did you include brackets? Ahh.. the reason it worked for you. I wonder you have got the idea by now. I dont think brackets in every database as standard sql works to escape reserved keywords names.